# Django mysql too many connections

Tags: mysql, django

I use Django with mysql, and having this problem of too many connections.

I run python script from command line, but integrated with Django model to check the data from database. The script runs every 30 seconds, and I use thread to control that. My_function is the function that will check db status.

```
while True: 
    now = time.time() 
    if now < next: 
        time.sleep(next - now) 
        t = Thread(target=my_function,)
        t.start()# start a thread

    next += interval
```

The problem is when I monitor mysql server. There are about 10 connections all the time, and all of them are sleeping. I just don't understand why. There are 2 active python threads running constantly, and all the other threads are terminated when they finish. How come the mysql connection are like 10?
Anyone can help me? Much appreciate!

Update 1:
Now put the screenshot of mysql processlist. The connections are all in sleep mode and does nothing, and the thread that creates the connection already terminates. That's really strange.

```
+------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
| Id   | User | Host            | db       | Command | Time  | State | Info             |
+------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
|  411 | root | localhost:47347 | NULL     | Sleep   |     2 |       | NULL             |
|  412 | root | localhost:47350 | NULL     | Sleep   |     3 |       | NULL             |
|  479 | root | localhost       | NULL     | Sleep   | 27164 |       | NULL             |
|  918 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   | 14006 |       | NULL             |
|  953 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   | 12956 |       | NULL             |
|  989 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   | 11874 |       | NULL             |
| 1025 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   | 10796 |       | NULL             |
| 1061 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  9716 |       | NULL             |
| 1097 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  8636 |       | NULL             |
| 1132 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  7586 |       | NULL             |
| 1168 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  6506 |       | NULL             |
| 1204 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  5426 |       | NULL             |
| 1240 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  4346 |       | NULL             |
| 1276 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  3266 |       | NULL             |
| 1312 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  2186 |       | NULL             |
| 1348 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |  1106 |       | NULL             |
| 1384 | root | localhost       | EZ_Green | Sleep   |    26 |       | NULL             |
| 1385 | root | localhost       | NULL     | Query   |     0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

As dusty said,

> Every thread that uses Django ORM creates a new database connection.
>   And Django will not manage the connection automatically that created by your own thread.
>   So you should manage it.

You can simple do this before each thread exit:

```
from django.db import connection

# your work thread method 

def my_function():
    # do something...
    # close the db connection explicitly

    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Please, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435673/using-django-orm-in-threads-and-avoiding-too-many-clients-exception-by-using-b)

Every thread that uses Django ORM creates a new database connection.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. But the strange thing is that after one thread terminates, the mysql connection is still there and lasts for a long time but only in sleep mode. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not specific to your question but rather to the title and might help someone else, In my company we got this message and couldn't figure out where it was originating.
After backtracking we found out that using django built-in Site model with debug mode caused a lot of connections to stay open.

We ended up setting a timeout on DB connections that are open more then 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was because all the views were using the `@login_required`.

Sometimes this decorator is unnecessary and it creates new connections for each query. Use it wisely, and also you can use `connection.close()` to close the connection before moving to the next task.

Answer (score 0):

Django in debug mode, creates a new thread for each request it handles, negating the effect of persistent connections. From [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#caveats)

> The development server creates a new thread for each request it handles, negating the effect of persistent connections. Don’t enable them during development.