# Django: Too many open client connections

Tags: python, django

I am using Django on EC2 server.
After a while, the number of open connections with clients increases to a very high number (>500) (I find the number using command "sudo lsof -i :8919 | wc -l").

Now, this is not easily reproducible, but I see that when the server this happens, I see requests coming in, but no response sent.

Note that this is client connection and not memcache or db connection.

How can I debug the issue? What can be the possible causes?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you deploy Django? What are you running in Django?

Comment: I just sync it with git. What I run in Django - A web-app. I guess you want some specific information, when you asked that. Could you please clarify?

Comment: How do you start Django on the server?

Comment: "python manage.py runserver". This has very low load and so I am not using apache

Comment: The runserver is not meant to,run in production, it's a development tool. Please use a proper WSGI setup. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Comment: I am setting up apache now.
But I still do not understand why I would get this error with runserver.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74574555/1904990), you can disable debug mode. Also you can add [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-CONN_MAX_AGE) to persist connections.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33270601)